# split 3D numpy to 3 diffrent arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, voxel, numpy-slicing

I have numpy.array pf shape (64 , 64 , 64)
I would like to split it on to 3 variables ,so

```
x.shape ==> (64) 

y.shape ==> (64) 

z.shape ==> (64)
```

as each dim represent voxels coordinate (x,y,z)  , I tried use `dsplit()` but no luck. any suggestion?

Comment: An array of shape `(64, 64, 64)` has 64**3 entries. Your three arrays have only 3*64 entries in total. How do you reduce this?

Comment: oh yeah my bad , I want to be  `x,y,z = 64**3(for each)` , so the shape (3, 262144)

Comment: If your initial array has shape `(64, 64, 64)`, then it has 64³ = 262,144 elements in total. You cannot get three arrays, `x`, `y` and `z` each having also 64³ elements from it, unless they are three copies of the original array. Maybe you can give a small example of what input and what output you would like to get? (e.g. for an input size `(3, 3, 3)` or `(4, 4, 4)`)

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is probably `transpose` + `ravel`:

```
X = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
>>> X
 ([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]],

   [[18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Your `x,y,z`:

```
>>> X.transpose((0,1,2)).ravel()
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
   17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26])

>>> X.transpose((1,2,0)).ravel()
array([ 0,  9, 18,  1, 10, 19,  2, 11, 20,  3, 12, 21,  4, 13, 22,  5, 14,
   23,  6, 15, 24,  7, 16, 25,  8, 17, 26])

>>> X.transpose((2,0,1)).ravel()
array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24,  1,  4,  7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22,
   25,  2,  5,  8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26])
```